# Stopping of integral vs stopping of integrator

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

For $B$ a Brownian motion and $\Phi\in\Lambda_\text{loc}^2$, do we have for all stopping times $\tau$
$$
\left(\int_0^\cdot \phi_s \, dB_s\right)^\tau = \int_0^\cdot \phi_s \, dB^\tau_s?$$

This question should make sense as $B^\tau$ is an Ito-process and integration w.r.t. to Ito processes is defined.

Comment: Would you please be more precise about the space $\Phi\in\Lambda_\text{loc}^2$ regards

Comment: Anyway this is true if I understand your notation this way. The process $\left(\int_0^\cdot \phi_s \, dB_s\right)_t^\tau=\int_0^{t\wedge \tau} \phi_s \, dB_s$ and the process $(\int_0^\cdot \phi_s \, dB^\tau_s)_t =\int_0^t \phi_s \, dB_{s\wedge \tau} $ it suffices to split at fixed $\omega$ the cases  $t<\tau(\omega)$ and  $t>\tau(\omega)$

Comment: @TheBridge Yes, you understand the notation right. I don't really follow your argument, I thought path-wise argumentation was not possible for the stochastic integral... $\Phi\in\Lambda_\text{loc}^2$ is the space of all progressive $\Phi$ such that $\int_0^t \Phi_s^2 ds$ is a.s. finite for all $t$.

Comment: Well if you to go this way, then start with simple processes and go all the way through, maybe some Monotone Class Theorem might accelerate the proof. regards